# How to enable tickering with TextField's?

Tags: java-me, textfield, lwuit

I want that when the length of the text of a TextField is larger than the TextField's preferredWidth then the TextField should ticker. How to achieve that ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.java.net/forum/topic/mobile-embedded/lwuit/how-enable-tickering-textfields